# Create public database link to SQL Server using Windows Authentication

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, oracle, plsql

Is it possible to create public database link to SQL Server using Windows Authentication from an Oracle DB?

I can create the link

```
CREATE PUBLIC DATABASE LINK DB_LINK CONNECT TO "domain\user" IDENTIFIED BY "password" USING 'tns_name_entry';
```

But when I try a select statement

```
Select * from dual@DB_LINK
```

I get the following:

```
ORA-28545: error diagnosed by Net8 when connecting to an agent
Unable to retrieve text of NETWORK/NCR message 65535
ORA-02063: preceding 2 lines from DB_LINK
28545. 0000 -  "error diagnosed by Net8 when connecting to an agent"
*Cause:    An attempt to call an external procedure or to issue SQL
           to a non-Oracle system on a Heterogeneous Services database link
           failed at connection initialization.  The error diagnosed
           by Net8 NCR software is reported separately.
*Action:   Refer to the Net8 NCRO error message.  If this isn't clear,
           check connection administrative setup in tnsnames.ora
           and listener.ora for the service associated with the
           Heterogeneous Services database link being used, or with
           'extproc_connection_data' for an external procedure call.
Error at Line: 9 Column: 20
```

I can connect to the db, so it's not an issue of connection. The heterogeneous service has been created, and the listener.ora and tnsnames.ora have been edited. I'm wondering if I'm getting the error because I'm using Windows authentication. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out my problem. It has something to do with Oracle12. You have to start the listener as the local account. Go into services --> right click properties of the listener --> Log On. Also you don't need the domain when creating the database link.